# In NServiceBus, can I use both Pub/Sub messaging and Full Duplex at the same time?

Tags: .net, wcf, nservicebus, publish-subscribe, nservicebus4

We want to use NSB (NServiceBus) for our app development.
We have a bunch (~6) of services that will get hooked into the NSB and where publish/subscribe pattern makes perfect sense.
However, there is a configuration service also, where we need a simple request/reply (full duplex) pattern to get configuration data (settings, permissions, etc) from either a local DB a central remote DB server.

So the client would request the config data and immediately get a result back, which is illegal (according to the manual) when using the NSB with a pub/sub setup.

**Is there a way to do this using NSB anyway,without losing the cool features such as SLR and fault tolerance, error queues, etc.? Or would I just have to circumvent the NSB altogether and create a simple WCF service instead?**

Thank you.

Comment: "illegal (according to the manual)"? Care to share a link to that information? I'm very surprised because we run a setup where I work which combines point-to-point (one way + request/reply) and pub/sub and I've not had any problems with it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever if you say you are using both on the same bus I believe you. I can't find that specific paragraph in the doc right now. So you're saying when I use one bus, I can use it however I please -- Pub/Sub & Send/Replay, whatever?

Comment: As a general rule you should avoid queries across a service bus.  Although it is possible it is probably going to hurt :) --- since a service bus is focused on being asynchronous your system should be happy to wait for responses and not have any expectation that they will arrive any time soon.  If you *do* need synchronous response then go with something more direct (as Udi has mentioned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use both publish/subscribe and full-duplex request/response messaging together in a given solution - that's fine.

All that being said, for the specific example that you gave, I'd model it differently.

I'd consider using a configuration **component** (rather than "service") which can be called in-process. This DLL would make the call to the database and really the only thing dealing with remote calls is whether the connection string points to the local machine or a remote one.

Comment: Thanks Udi! I'm not quite sure I follow that "component" model. I was hoping that with NSB there is no such thing as a remote connection string. Data would always flow from the caller (client machine) through the service bus and handled on the other side (=the remote machine, or maybe the local achine depending on the setup) where the database is local anyway. Or how would the configuration component otherwise benefit from the service bus?

Comment: The configuration component wouldn't use NServiceBus - just regular ADO.NET to access the database. Not everything is supposed to use NServiceBus :)